# How to enable HTTPS pages on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003

I cannot load HTTPS pages - I am getting page not found!

I guess this is related to the server.

What can I do to enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL Port was blocked by the firewall. 
I added the port 443 to the windows firewall exceptions (TCP exception) and I managed to access the site using 'https://'

Answer (score 1):

You can install this hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP clients cannot obtain certificates
>   from a Windows Server 2008-based certification authority (CA) if the
>   CA is configured to use SHA2 256 or higher encryption

Comment: Any idea where this HotFix may be found?  It seems to has disappeared off the Microsoft site.